# List Azure Cloud services instances

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

In dotnet core I don't know how to list cloud services instances in a Cloud service.
I have tried the following code.
The resource group has 7 Cloud services + several other resources.
Only one cloud service is returned, not the one I want to browse.
Then, once I have the Cloud service, how do I list and count the cloud service instances?

```
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

var services = azure.AppServices.ResourceManager.Deployments.ListByResourceGroup("resourceGroupName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any dotnet library for this.
I used the rest apis instead.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-get-cloud-service-properties#request